# Trouble joining two tables - No results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I have a table named `phpbb_pcp_market` with these rows: http://pastebin.com/ZAFjawD8 (There are more obviously)

And I have another table named `phpbb_pcp_market_cart` that looks like this:

```
+----+---------+-----------+------------+
| id | item_id | player_id | time       |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+
| 14 |      49 |         3 | 1384806292 |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I need to join these two tables based on `item_id`, but for some reason it's not working.

This is the query I've used:

```
SELECT m.*, c.* FROM (phpbb_pcp_market_cart c) 
    LEFT JOIN phpbb_pcp_market m 
        ON (c.item_id = m.item_id) 
    WHERE c.player_id = 3 
    ORDER BY c.time
```

For some reason, it's returning nothing.

I can't figure what I did wrong in the query. And no, I'm not good at SQL.

Comment: Your query, given the data your describe, should be returning at least one row.  Can you clarify what you mean by "returning nothing" and what tool you are using for querying?

Comment: By returning nothing I mean it's returning 0 rows. I'm using PHP to execute that query.

Comment: I see nothing wrong. This query should return at least one row (if you have a row with `phpbb_pcp_market_cart.player_id = 3`, as you say. Then the problem lies with the PHP code.

Comment: Are you **sure** that there is a player_id = 3 in the cart table? Try removing the WHERE clause and see if that returns any rows. Then try a `select * from phpbb_pcp_market_cart where player_id = 3` and see if that returns any rows that has the correct item_id. There's a problem with the data (or your understanding of it), not the query.

Comment: Don't know, if it works with brackets around the FROM and ON part

Comment: Sorry for the trouble guys, there was a simple mistake I did not related to the query and I couldn't see it. I got it to work.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is maybe player_id is data type String?

Comment: @rubo77: it will work also with that brackets around.

Comment: What was your mistake, just for knowledge reasons?

Comment: I guess I rushed a bit while writing code and entered the wrong variable to execute as SQL. Ridiculous.

Comment: It happens.  I'm glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine with your SQL-code.

Look in the rest of your PHP-code if there is something wrong. The bug is not related to the SQL-part ;)

Answer (score -1):

First double check your data, your query seems to be OK.

If you want to select all items for specific `player_id` don't use `LEFT JOIN` but simple `JOIN`, because you will never get rows where it could be NULL.
Also braces can be left out for simplicity:

```
SELECT m.*, c.* FROM phpbb_pcp_market_cart c 
    JOIN phpbb_pcp_market m 
        ON c.item_id = m.item_id
    WHERE c.player_id = 3 
    ORDER BY c.time
```

Comment: I don't think this would help.   Agreed with above post; data should be checked first.

Comment: Changed answer to better explain how to improve query.

Comment: I think it is faster with a direct join, so if you don't need the NULL rows the Idea is good. You could also just use `SELECT m.*, c.* FROM phpbb_pcp_market_cart AS c, phpbb_pcp_market AS m WHERE c.item_id = m.item_id AND c.player_id = 3 `